# ipdb doesn't work in vim console

Tags: python, vim, pdb

ipdb works fine in the shell, but I want to debug under vim, after I set `ipdb.set_trace()`, and then `!python %`,
the console below gives me [this messy prompt](https://twitter.com/yozloy/statuses/246517294665175040), any idea?

Answer (score 4):

I guess you are using a GUI Vim. GVim? MacVim? The pseudo terminal you get when executing external tools is not, has never been and will probably never be able to understand the escape characters you see. That means *no color* and *no ncurses-style widgets*.

You'd better run it in a separate terminal or find a way to disable colors in iPython.

Comment: So there's **no way** to make it look pretty. Use an external terminal instead.

Comment: @romainl Don’t say “no way”, you can patch vim. You could have patched it even if it was closed source. Just understanding colors is simple (though I did it in VimL, not in C).

Comment: @ZyX, do you have a usable solution to this? If so I'd *really* like to try it. I wrote "no way" but I meant "no buit-in way such as `:set colorshell`". I'm really curious about your solution. I remember googling a bit about that subject 2 years ago without any success.

Comment: @romainl And I have a plugin which when being fed with `system()` output will produce colored output using `:echo`, preserving not only color but also some other specials (AFAIR only `\r`). But it is in alpha stage and not currently developed. Precisely, [this one](https://bitbucket.org/ZyX_I/ansi_esc_echo).

Comment: Yes I just did a google search with your username and found it 3 mins ago. You are right that ConqueTerm could be used as a workaround but it's really far from perfect. Well, using an external shell is not perfect either.

Answer (score 1):

If you don’t really want to patch vim as well as run in a separate terminal as @romainl suggests then there is [Conque](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2771) plugin which provides a way to have colored pseudo-terminal in a vim buffer. You have to run

```
ConqueTerm(|[V]Split|Tab) sh
```

and within it run

```
python path/to/file.py
```

(no `%` is possible) though. It can be narrowed down to a mapping:

```
nnoremap <expr> ,p ":\<C-u>ConqueTermVSplit sh\n\<C-o>:call feedkeys('python '.shellescape(bufname(".bufnr("%").")).\"\\n\")\n"
```

Answer (score 1):

I have created my own workaround for this which may be valuable to you depending on how you use ipdb. The idea is that you can pass in `no_colors=True` to `set_trace()` and that way the interactive debugger will not produce any colour output. I have also enabled this argument for `launch_ipdb_on_exception`.

This means that you can do:

```
import ipdb
ipdb.set_trace(no_colors=True)
```

And the output looks fine in MacVim.

To use this you will have to use my version of `ipdb`, which is [here](https://github.com/leifdenby/ipdb), actual relevant commit if you want to see what I did is [here](https://github.com/leifdenby/ipdb/commit/e29928683e8f414543a251cf8fabab3d6c745b7c#ipdb/__main__.py).

It turns out that `ipdb` is merely a convient way of accessing [`ipython.core.debugger`](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/api/generated/IPython.core.debugger.html), `Pdb` the actual debugger is defined there.

Answer (score 1):

For windows users i suggest [ConEmu](https://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/). Works perfectly with ipdb (highlighting, auto-complete, ...)